# What are the latest/best practices for index generation?

Tags: indexing, subdividing

I would like to know what the current best practices are for index generation. What are the best packages/programs to use and which ones to avoid. What are the best ones to use for generating multiple indices?

I know that this kind of a question can generate a variety of responses based upon one's personal opinion.  Please share why you like your particular options.

Comment: The reason I ask: I inherited a LaTeX document that was very old (LaTeX 2.09) and was tasked with updating it. I have updated it to LaTeX 2e, but I'm having trouble creating the index.  The old document used the `makeidx` option and `\input{XXXX.ind}` which, if I understand correctly is a bad/old way of doing things.

The old document used commands like `\index{xyz}` and `\index{abcd@{\ty abcd}}`. When I include `\usepackage{makeidx}` then I get an error that the `\index` command doesn't exist. Are these still the correct way to add index entries?

Comment: It's quite strange that `\index` is undefined, as it has a (dummy) definition in the kernel. It's probably some other command that doesn't exist, check the log file. The method is still `\usepackage{makeidx}`, then `\index{...}`; the index is printed with `\printindex` (as it was also in LaTeX209).

Comment: Try adding `\makeindex` after `\usepackage{makeidx}` in the preamble. With documents somewhere in-between LaTeX 2.09 and 2e it might help. (And please give feedback whether this worked.)

Comment: Okay, so I'm kind of embarrassed. I found out that there was a `makeidx.sty` file in the directory of TeX files. That was messing things up. Once I removed that file, LaTeX compiles just fine until after `makeindex` is run. Then I get the error (not sure if you'll be able to see the formatting correctly, the line break comes after `\ty`): `! Undefined control sequence.
l.23   \item {\ty
                  a10}, \hyperpage{41}
? 
`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
\documentclass{book}
...
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex
...

\begin{document}
...
text\index{abc@{\ty abc}} and other text...
...

\printindex

\end{document}
```

This should work and, apart from `\usepackage` instead of an option to `\documentstyle` has always been the method also in LaTeX209.

Check what the undefined command is, it would be very strange if it were `\index`.

For multiple indices there is a choice between a few packages:

- **multind** (actually a LaTeX209 package)
- **index**
- **splitidx**
- **imakeidx**

I wouldn't recommend **index** that's not as customizable as the last two ones. The advantages of **imakeidx** over **splitidx** are that it can compile automatically all indices during the LaTeX run and that it's compatible with **idxlayout** that extends its customization possibilities. It also supports `xindy` (as **splitidx** does). (Disclaimer: I'm one of the authors of **imakeidx**.)

Comment: Thanks for the simple example. I tried it with success (after removing the `\ty` command. See my comment above.

Answer (score 7):

for multiple indexes look at the packages `splitidx` or `index` from the `camel` bundle,
which I prefer. If you have utf8 characters to sort then give `xindy` a try, it is more powerful than the old `makeindex` program

Comment: I have used `splitidx`, but it seemed a little cumbersome to me. I think I had seen `index` before but never tried it. What are some benefits of `index` over `splitidx`?

Comment: it is easier to use, from my point of view ...

Comment: it looks like an equivalent of `biblatex` (a super package able to address all possibilities with the new engine `biber`) for indices would be welcome.

Comment: A big problem with the `index` package is that it redefines a bunch of basic tex macros that primarily have nothing to do with index generation, like `\markright/\markboth`, `\addtocontents`, `\@starttoc`, and `\raggedbottom/\flushbottom`. So be carefull if you use other packages that also mess with these macros.

Comment: All of these commands are used when creating an index!