# List of Indexing Packages - Pros and Cons

Tags: packages, indexing, big-list

What are the various indexing packages and what are their pros and cons?  When should one choose one over the other?

There is some discussion of this in [What are the latest/best practices for index generation?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32892/what-are-the-latest-best-practices-for-index-generation), but I would prefer to have more details about each package.

Comment: Sounds like a case for CW and one package per answer? What would be relevant categories of information to be included in each answer?

Comment: @doncherry I'd rather have [tag:indexing] specialists answer this in a single pass and gain reputation for their answer.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The features provided by the various indexing packages may be divided into three categories:

1. Supporting multiple indexes;
2. Providing macros that simplify index generation;
3. Allowing for customization of the index layout.

The [`Topic Index`](http://texcatalogue.sarovar.org/bytopic.html) of the TeX Catalogue lists about a dozen index-related packages; this overview is about the packages I've used (or at least read the manual).

[`makeidx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/makeidx), a *"[s]tandard package for creating indexes"*, provides some index-related macros like `\printindex` which (for whatever reason) are not part of the LaTeX2e kernel (like `\makeindex` and `\index`) or the standard document classes (like the `theindex` environment).

[`multind`](http://ctan.org/pkg/multind) *"redefines [the] `\makeindex`, `\index` and `\printindex` commands to deal with multiple indexes"*. The package predates LaTeX2e; it doesn't work with the AMS classes, and index headings won't be formatted corresponding to other chapter/section headings.

[`index`](http://ctan.org/pkg/index) *"supports multiple indexes in a single document and provides a more robust `\index` command"*. The package also offers `\index*` which typesets a word and creates an index entry for it as well. `index` is likely to produce incorrectly formatted index headings for non-standard classes.

[`splitidx`/splitindex](http://ctan.org/pkg/splitindex) allow *"more than 16 indexes: `splitidx` outputs only a single file `\jobname.idx` and the program [splitindex] splits that file into several raw index files and calls your favorite index processor for each of the files"*. The `splitidx` package offers the `\extendtheindex` macro that adds various hooks to the `theindex` environment; the actual customization of the latter is left to the user.

[`imakeidx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/imakeidx) *"enables the user to produce and typeset one or more indexes simultaneously with a document"* by using the shell-escape feature of modern TeX distributions. `imakeidx` is able to call the splitindex program (see above), and it features a key--value interface to customize various aspects of the index layout (including the possibility to call the MakeIndex program with a certain `.ist` style file). Originally, `imakeidx` was not compatible with the `memoir` class (which uses an idiosyncratic method to generate indexes), but v1.1 of the package does away with that restriction.

[`hvindex`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hvindex) *"simplifies the indexing of words [...] [T]o index a word in a text, you only have to type it once; the package makes sure it is both typeset and indexed"*. The package offers a bunch of macros that control the formatting of index entries; the package manual is silent about whether those macros may be used for the creation of multiple indexes.

[`idxlayout`](http://ctan.org/pkg/idxlayout) "*offers a key--value interface to configure index layout parameters [and] is responsive to the index-related options and commands of the `KOMA-Script` and `memoir` classes"*. `idxlayout` does only deal with the `theindex` environment, not with `.ist` style files; it may be used on top of `index`, `splitidx`, and `imakeidx`. (Disclosure: I'm the package author.)

[`repeatindex`](http://ctan.org/pkg/repeatindex) "*repeats [the] item of an index if a page or column break occurs within a list of subitems"*. The package README (from 2001) states that `repeatindex` *"has not been tested much, yet"* and lists some known problems.

[`indextools`](https://ctan.org/pkg/indextools) is a modern fork by Maïeul Rou­quette of `imakeidx` that introduces compatibility with `bidi` for bi-directonal language typesetting.

Comment: I think one import point is the processor. I like `xindy`.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel I'll see if I can come up with something in the next days -- but comparing MakeIndex and xindy could be the topic of another answer, too.

Comment: The links are broken; there seems to be a bug on CTAN's website: the /index part of the url leads to an index of all packages

Comment: @lockstep, have you given a thought to include MakeIndex and xindy in the answer? It has been a while now ...

Comment: @lockestep this list is extremely useful and probably used by a lot of people -- it is missing though a very important package: `indextools`, which is a modern fork of eGreg's `imakeidx` by Maïeul Rouquette. Would you be able to edit the answer and add just a simple paragraph about it?