# Practically, where to put \index?

Tags: indexing, best-practices

I use vim-latex.  For the sake of SyncTeX, I usually format my paragraphs into separate lines, using a customized `gqip`.

I used to put `\index` after the term to be indexed, as suggested [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32892/what-are-the-latest-best-practices-for-index-generation). For example

```
Bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla. A 
\emph{quasipseudometaball}\index{quasipseudometaball} is defined as follows
```

However, this produces a long string without spaces, which is not practical when I format the paragraph in Vim with `gqip`, as shown in the example above.

Putting space or line break before `\index` is not a good idea, neither, because

```
Let $B$ be a ball \index{ball}.
```

will put a space before the period. Anyway, putting `\index` within the text makes the defining paragraphs unreadable in the source code.  I don't like it.

I now decide to put them before the relative paragraphs, but sometimes the paragraph is long, and the location is not precise anymore.

It may be a silly question, but I would like to know where do you put `\index`?

Comment: I usually hide the `\index` inside a macro. So instead of doing `ball\index{ball}` I'll do `\term{ball}` or something similar and then define `\term` (or whatever) to use `\index`. (Although that additionally requires escaping `makeindex` special characters etc, unless I use `\usepackage[index]{glossaries}` which does it for me.)

Comment: Related with Nicola Talbot comment, event you can make that the  word is showed differently the fisrt time but indexed in the same way, and more ... There are an example of some complexity  in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/116436/provide-boolean-from-two-arguments-case-insensitives for a example

Comment: It also seems to me that I get different kerning for punctuation if I do `cats\index{cat}.` or `cats.\index{cat}` - the second seems to work better.

Comment: What about putting the `\index` before the paragraph that contains the keywords? I guess most people just start reading a paragraph from the beginning.